# GridLayout and dynamic views

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to use a GridLayout to reproduce a layout similar to what we currently se on the Android Market (I mean Play Store !).

[image: Google Play Store layout]

Now I managed to do something relatively similar :

[image: My layout]

This looks nice, but I do not think this would scale well with many Views if I used bitmaps instead of colors for the backgrounds of the Views. As I understand GridLayout cannot use an adapter, so I would have to manage myself the management of Views when they are shown/hidden.

Any suggestions ? I don't have to use a gridlayout if this layout is possible with another view that I can plug to an adapter.

Comment: I'm not sure what your concern is when you say "when they are shown/hidden". Do the sections change, or are they static?

Comment: well there could be many sections, it would scroll down (the sections are populated dynamically via a json file)

Comment: I think i will go with a listview and an arrayadapter. getView() will create a gridLayout where i can have 1 or multiple views. the only hickup will be that i will need to use the onclick event of the subviews instead of the onitemclick event of the adapter

Comment: @yann.debonnel Did you have any luck rolling your own Adapter for GridLayout?

Comment: Can you share the layout code for the screen you created? Thank you

Comment: @yann.debonnel Did you found any solution for your question?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no magic solution that will auto-populate your views. This is a pretty custom case. Your best bet will be to set a few timers that will periodically load/update the content of each of the sections. You will have to create/destroy/animate all of the views yourself. But I like the idea and glad to see that you are trying to make attractive dynamic content.